# writing back the aggregated data from mongoDB into different collection

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have some data in **mongodb** from that I am finding a group of data and storing it back to the different mongo collection. This is the approach that I have tried. But It is giving me error.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
Client= MongoClient()
db= Client["myntra"]
collection= db["women.trouser"]
pipeline=[]
pipeline = [
    {'$group':
         {'_id':
              {'objectId':"$_id",
               'styleOptions_skuAvailabilityDetailMap_availableCount':"$pdpData.styleOptions.skuAvailabilityDetailMap.19.availableCount",
               'styleOptions_skuId':"$pdpData.styleOptions.skuId",}
          }
     }
]



cursor = db.women.duplicate.trouser.aggregate(pipeline,{'$out':'women.duplicate.trouser'})#{ 'allowDiskUse': True}))
print cursor
```

Comment: What is the error message? what `#` is doing inside the `.aggregate()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems :

Firstly the [aggregation operator $out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) is part of the pipeline. PyMongo [aggregate()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method accepts all of the pipeline stages as the first param.

So you should combine your $out into the pipeline variable, for example:

```
pipeline = [
     {'$group': { ... } },
     {'$out': { ... } }   
]
```

For more examples see [PyMongo Aggregation Examples](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html)

Second, you are specifying the output collection to be the same as the input collection. Note that $out operator [replaces existing collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#replace-existing-collection). See also [$out examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#example)

To sum up, below is your code above with some fixes:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client= MongoClient()
collection= db["myntra"]["women.trouser"]
pipeline = [
    {'$group':
         {'_id':
              {'objectId':"$_id",               
               'styleOptions_skuAvailabilityDetailMap_availableCount':"$pdpData.styleOptions.skuAvailabilityDetailMap.19.availableCount",
               'styleOptions_skuId':"$pdpData.styleOptions.skuId",}
          }
     }, 
    {'$out': 'women.duplicate.trouser' }
]

cursor = db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, { 'allowDiskUse': True} )
print cursor
```

The snippet above was written for PyMongo v3.3 and MongoDB v3.2.x